# Omega 4 drush install after omega 3 removal: could not locate Gemfile libraries not installed, drush omega-guard fails

Tags: theming

I unsinstalled Omega 3 , and then installed omega 4 (by drush) and created the subtheme (`drush omega-wizard`).
Everything seems to work, but the js  libraries like `csspie` are not present.
Also, when I try to run `drush omega-guard`, i get the error message `There was no Gemfile at sites/all/themes/xxx`
It's a single site installation, and omega drush commands work. Changing to the theme directory (as per [Drush Omega Guard - "command could not be found" or "could not locate Gemfile"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96929/drush-omega-guard-command-could-not-be-found-or-could-not-locate-gemfile)) did not alter the results.
Running linux (ubuntu 14.04 with the  LAMPP from the official repositories ) 
I have another site on that server (my local dev machine) with Omega 4 and everyting works well there.

Comment: Install missing libraries, maybe?

Comment: Sorry, bad wording :-)
I know i can install them, what worries me is that  they should be installed by drush by default. I changed the subject title now, thanks